# Saving date/time using mongomapper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

Im trying to save date time information to the following field in mongo

```
key :last_comment_time_cache, DateTime

update_attributes!({:last_comment_time_cache => Time.now})
```

The data that is being saved is missing the time

```
"last_comment_time_cache": {
    "$date": "2013-03-23T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?, Thanks Nath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the field type to `Time` instead of `DateTime`. If you watch their `Date` extension [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/extensions/date.rb) (`Date` is the [parent](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) of `DateTime`)  they are only taking `day,month and year` into account to construct the date that will be sent to mongo, that's not the case for their [Time](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/extensions/time.rb) implementation.